# How to save child entities without saving parent for each transaction

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions

I am using Spring Data JPA  repositories. I have a Card entity and a Transaction entity. When user perform a transaction with card then i would like to save Card and transaction(purchase/refund) entities both. But when user performs next transaction then i want to save Transaction entity only. My Entities are :

```
Card Entity

@Entity
@Table(name = "CARD")
public class Card {


    @Id
    private Long card_id;

    public Long getCard_id() {
        return card_id;
    }

    public void setCard_id(Long card_id) {
        this.card_id = card_id;
    }


    private String type;

}

Transaction Entity

@Entity
@Table(name="Transaction")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator( name="TRAN_SEQ1", initialValue=5,sequenceName="TRAN_SEQ1", allocationSize=1 )
    @GeneratedValue( strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="TRAN_SEQ1")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "card_id")
    private Card card;

    public Card getCard() {
        return card;
    }

    public void setCard(Card card) {
        this.card = card;
    }

}
```

I have tried with below approach but it throws below exception on save:

```
Transaction t = new Transaction();
Card c = cardRepository.getOne(123L);
t.setCard(c);
transactionRepository.save(t);
**Exception :       
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()**
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Can anyone guide me here..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the reverse relationship?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARD")
public class Card {


    @Id
    private Long card_id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    // Getters and Setters

}
```

Comment: :- your approach worked. I had to set object like below : Transaction t = new Transaction();  t.setTransactionId("E123");  Card c1 = new Card();
c1.setCard_id(123L);
List<Transaction> lst = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
t.setCard(c1);
lst.add(t); c1.setTransactions(l);
cardRepository.save(c1);   But dont you think set card in transaction and transaction list in card is making it cyclic which is not good.  Also Can you  pls tell me why its not working reverse way.  Logically it doesn't make sense to use cardRepository to save transaction every time ?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working to be honest, I'd need to put some code together and try it out. Theoretically, you can have a TransactionRepo and a CardRepo and to should save a Card without any problems without the need to set the Transactions and to save the Transactions you would need to set the Card.

Comment: I'd believe you should be able to save Transactions setting without the need of the reverse relationship but I've been wrong before :)